# LINQ select a date range to join on other queries

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I wish to create a LINQ query that will result in a resultset that contains a range of dates. I want to give it 2012-09-01 and 2012-09-05 and it should return a resultset containing:

- 2012-09-01
- 2012-09-02
- 2012-09-03
- 2012-09-04
- 2012-09-05

I want this because I wish to use it in a join for subsequent queries, that may not contain all dates. However, I want the final result to contain all dates in the interval, regardless of whether any of the other queries returned any results.

I use LINQ to Entities.

As a real example, it could look something like this:

```
from p in projects
where p.StartDate > dateFrom && p.StartDate < dateTo
// somehow 'select' every date between dateFrom and dateTo,
// so you get one row in the resultset for each date in between.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to create a `Dates` table:

```
create table Dates (
 Date DATE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
)
```

And fill it appropriately. T-SQL does not have arrays or generator functions.

The clustered index on this table will make it fast to select a small sub-range of all possible dates.

You can also add more columns like `DayOfWeek TINYINT NOT NULL`, `IsHoliday BIT NOT NULL`, ...  Very handy.

Let me also mention the possibility to fill in the missing dates in your application code. I think it depends on your exact situation if that is better or not. Especially if you want the joined results to use for further server-side processing you probably need a dates table.

Comment: Good valid answer. I am hoping not having to make a table like that. I was hoping more for something like `from o in [something] where date > intervalFrom group by day select firstordefault` (this example is pseudo code)

Comment: You can create a view or TVF to generate such a list using constructions such as `select from (values (1), (2), (3), ...)` to generate numbers and dates but this is just as nasty. It gets unwieldy and for dates I cannot see a way to make it perform well (not generate the entire list of 10k possible dates and filter it down).

Comment: Btw, these "generated tables" do work well in practice. I even have one with all numbers in [1..1M]. It sounds so nasty at first but you learn to like it... There is no better way.

Comment: I may be expanding on the scope of this question, but could you possible tell me how I can use your Dates table with a query like the one I added in my question?

Comment: Sure. Create the table, fill it, import the schema, and join it to the projects table `from d in dates join p in projects on ... into j from p in j.DefaultIfEmpty()` LINQ does not have right joins so we need to to a reversed left join.

Comment: I have a feeling you skipped some important bits in the `...`. If I join directly on the dates and use a left join, it would only find the projects on the rows that exactly match the date of that row, right?

Comment: Yes it would match exactly for all dates in your range of dates. All those dates will appear, and all projects whose date is in that range. My understanding is that this is what you want (please correct me if not).

Answer (score 0):

To start with, it sounds like you just want a `where` clause along the lines of:

```
where foo.Date >= startDate && foo.Date < endDate
```

where you'd make `endDate` an *exclusive* bound (e.g. midnight on September 6th) in order to catch any date/time values which were "during September 5th".

You can then group the results by date... I would do post-processing in .NET (in LINQ to Objects) to handle dates which have no results. That's likely to be significantly simpler than trying to do it within the Entity Framework code.

Comment: I understand this, but I'm looking for the other approach. I can't use post-processing to fill in empty dates, as I need to join the LINQ query with another LINQ query and they need to run together against the database (with a third and fourth query as well)

Comment: But in a join where there's no results in one side, wouldn't you get no results anyway, so you could post-process even that? If you really can't, then usr's answer may well be the only sane one.

Comment: I know it sounds strange, but I'm investigating one way to solve a problem that, in itself, would be too complex for stackoverflow. I may very well end up solving it a different way. Thanks though.